# Search by file dimension

Tags: files, search, images

I have many photos. How to search files by its dimensions? For example, i want to search images with exact dimensions 500 x 500 pixels. Is there any utility for this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `identify` command that's part of ImageMagick to do this:

```
$ identify rose.jpg
rose.jpg JPEG 640x480 sRGB 87kb 0.050u 0:01
```

The 640x480 is the dimensions of the image, rose.jpg.

Using the `find` command you could do something like this:

```
$ find somedir -iname '*.jpg' -exec identify {} \;
```

So for your example:

```
$ find somedir -iname '*.jpg' -exec "identify {} awk '{print $1, $3}' \
       | grep '500x500'" \;
```

#### References

- [ImageMagick identify command examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php)

Comment: This is suitable only for files without whitespace characters in their name. Better use `-format` option: `identify -format '%P %f\n' *.{jpg,png,gif} | grep '^500x500 '`.

Comment: @manatwork, that technique didn't work too well for me, running it in a directory where there aren't any png, jpg, or gif files yields this error: "identify: unable to open image `*.jpg':  @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2517."

Comment: Being a comment, I kept it simple. Feel free to combine it with your original `find` based code.

Comment: I like your thinking on the approach, just was putting a comment to it in case others encountered it too 8-).

Answer (score 5):

With `exiftool`:

```
exiftool -q -r -if '$ImageHeight == 500 && 
  $ImageWidth == 500' -p '$Directory/$FileName' /some/dir
```